# Database Triggers and ECA ( Event Condition and Action )

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am new to **Triggers** in database and **ECA**.
According to my understanding, Triggers are the automated procedures in PL/SQl that are fired based upon some Event and Condition which is provide by ECA.
But does ECA has its own independent significance in database, it some independent system? or How do Triggers and ECA relate to each other ?

Any help on the above topics is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Triggers mechanism allows to bind custom procedures to low level DML operations like insert, update and delete. Procedures are created by language used by data base, for example: oracle uses pl/sql, sql server uses tsql and other can use others.

For example:
Developer can create trigger on delete operation on table customers that invoke procedure that create log.

You can say Trigger is fulfilling ECA concept.
Event - is DML operation on data.
Condition - defined during trigger creation.
Action - procedure defined by developer.

Comment: Just to add - not only DML but also DDL on schema/DB or system events